# Should i be using the picture tag in bootstrap so i have 4 different pictures of the same image for each size screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-images

Just a quick one as i can not seem to find anything on this one anywhere.
I am using bootstrap 4 css and some JavaScript to make my first website for a portfolio. 
I know that my page is responsive now but i'm wondering should i be using 4 different size images of the same picture with the picture tag or is it ok just to compress the one picture down to a reasonable size for example 60kb
then use this one image for all screen sizes as it will be responsive..
Just wondered what all you professional developers do as i am still a novice and do not know how it is done.   what would you do if you were making a website using bootstrap 4 images one for each breakpoint with the picture tag and max/min width...or just go for the easier option and have one image for all less code but im guessing that it may be a longer loading time on a mobile device??

..sorry i do not have the code to show you guys it is just i have not got round to figuring out how to use the picture ta with bootstrap and i am still at the stage of compressing all of my images.

Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you know about `srcset` https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/ ? did you use it and did it fail ?

Comment: NO i did not know about itand have not tried it yet..Thanks for letting me know and for your reply. Im using bootstrap 4 for the website im.designing so it is fully responsive anyway but my image files were to big and the page was taking too long to load...whilst trying to find the best way to compress my image file sizes i watched something online that said o should be using different images for different size user screens as if it would take longer to load on a mobile device and it kind of baffeled me as to to whether i should be doing this when using bootstrap.